# Android Emulator Failed to create Context 0x3005

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am entirely new to Android development, and I am trying to do a small task in Android (a registration form). However, I am getting the following error:

```
[2013-12-05 11:06:26 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-12-05 11:06:26 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-12-05 11:06:26 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-12-05 11:06:26 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-12-05 11:06:26 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-12-05 11:06:26 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-12-05 11:06:26 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-12-05 11:06:26 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-12-05 11:06:26 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
```

I Increased RAM size 768(previously 512)for Android 4.4 API level 19, but I am getting
Failed to create Context 0x3005 
[2013-12-05 13:55:54 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer. wglGetExtensionsStringARB 
[2013-12-05 13:55:55 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 1455 –

So approximately how much memory is needed to run the android application?

Now i am getting error like this,

> [2013-12-05 17:36:00 - Helloworld] New emulator found: emulator-5554
>   [2013-12-05 17:36:00 - Helloworld] Waiting for HOME
>   ('android.process.acore') to be launched... [2013-12-05 17:40:41 -
>   Helloworld] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554' [2013-12-05 17:40:41
>   - Helloworld] Uploading Helloworld.apk onto device 'emulator-5554' [2013-12-05 17:40:42 - Helloworld] Installing Helloworld.apk...
>   [2013-12-05 17:42:56 - Helloworld] Failed to install Helloworld.apk on
>   device 'emulator-5554! [2013-12-05 17:42:56 - Helloworld] (null)
>   [2013-12-05 17:42:57 - Helloworld] Launch canceled!

Comment: I got the same errors too. I used Galaxy Nexus and all default settings. Oh, my Windows XP is on Microsoft VPC. Funny thing is, not like some ppl mentioned to increase RAM for AVD, but I decreased from the default 1024 to 512 since I saw a hint in AVD to decrease RAM. then my first Android app poped up in the AVD!

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps and see if its working.

- Go to AVD Manager
- Select the device
- click Edit and uncheck the Enabled checkbox

If this not work than try to increase RAM of your emulator

you can Increase RAM of emulator as below

```
Eclipse->Window->Android Virtual Device Manager->From the list of emulator, choose your emulator->Click on Edit->And Check Memory Option-> here Increase your Emulator RAM Size
```

After Doing this restart your emulator

Comment: I am getting same Error

Comment: Try to increase RAM of emulator

Comment: I Increased RAM size 768(previously 512)for Android 4.4 API level 19.But I am getting    Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2013-12-05 13:55:54 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
 wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-12-05 13:55:55 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 1455

Answer (score 1):

I faced the below error and was not able to launch the emulator,

[2014-01-18 09:51:14 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005

[2014-01-18 09:51:14 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.

[2014-01-18 09:51:14 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 8

Solution:
I chose the emulator device that consumed lesser RAM and was able to launch the emulator successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the response and welcome to Stack Overflow! Do you have some more details on choosing the right emulator device (or where to look for RAM consumption for the different devices you have, or perhaps how to create different emulated devices with less RAM)?

Answer (score 0):

You should update your cart graphic driver

Answer (score 0):

Click on AVD Manager icon on toolbar and select your device and edit this then in Emulated Performance unchecked Use Host GPU

This worked for me