# my android emulater not working

Tags: android

How can i fix this problem?

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'Nexus_One'
Failed to create Context 0x3005
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: warning: opening audio output failed
Could not initialize emulated framebufferERROR: Could not create renderer: Couldn't find matching render driver
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its all related to the size of ram you define for your avd .See this [Android-emulator-failed-to-create-context-0x3005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392582/android-emulator-failed-to-create-context-0x3005).

Answer (score 0):

i had this issue using android studio in a virtual win7 machine. I used this bundle adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip instead of android emulator, added 4.4.2 sdk platform and system images and worked properly.

Are you working on VM's? In that case, perhaps this workaround work for you.